# JavaScript conditional statement with check for empty returns string

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript you can check whether a variable has any value like this

```
if (strValue) {
    //do something
}
```

Today I encountered something beyond my understanding, a conditional where I used this wasn't working as I expected. I had some JavaScript code that looked similar to below snippet.

```js
var blnX = false;
var intX = 3;
var strX = "2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z";

function test(blnValue, intValue, strValue) {
    return !blnValue && (intValue == 2 || ((intValue == 3 || intValue == 4) && strValue));
}

var result = test(blnX, intX, strX);
```

At this point I expected `result` to be `true` but it contained `"2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z"`.

When I change the `return` statement like below,

```js
return (((intValue == 3 || intValue == 4) && strValue) || intValue == 2) && !blnValue;
```

or like this,

```js
return !blnValue && (intValue == 2 || (strValue && (intValue == 3 || intValue == 4)));
```

then it does return `true`.

To make it even more confusing when I change the function from the above snippet like below, then it does work like expected.

```js
function test(blnValue, intValue, strValue) {
    if (!blnValue && (intValue == 2 || ((intValue == 3 || intValue == 4) && strValue)))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the conditional from the `return` statement used in the first function is not returning the expected boolean value?

Comment: You probably should not use non binary values in binary operators. It may lead to unintuitive behaviour like that, especially knowing that `0` or `""` (empty string) are falsy values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to understand how `||` or `&&` work.

`2 && 3` will return `3`, because if the left operand is *truthy*, the right operand is returned. That's all.

It works in a `if` because `3` is truthy, so

```
if(2 && 3) {
    console.log("bip"); // will be displayed.
}
```

Truthy/falsy and boolean values are two different things.

Some reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: *Similar customers also purchased*: **The `??` Nullish Coalescing Operator** (treats `null` and `undefined` as "even falsier" than other falsy values) -- **[Add to Cart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)**

Comment: Thanks! Especially the links to the MDN Web Docs are enlightening!

Answer (score 0):

`||` is in fact coalescing operator, not logical OR. It returns first non-falsey value of its operands, or last value otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Expressions don't always return `true` or `false` in Javascript. They return the value of the last thing that they evaluated.

An easy trick to convert anything to `true` or `false` is to use a double-exclamation. One exclamation will give the opposite of the truthfulness of the expression, so two will switch it back to its original boolean equivalent.

See the sample code.

```js
const a = 'hello'
const b = 1
console.log(b && a)
// outputs 'hello' since 'a' was the last evaluated thing
console.log(b || a)
// outputs 1 since 'b' was truthy and no need to evaluate a
console.log(!!(b || a))
// outputs true since !! quickly converts to boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it might help to consider, step by step, how `return !blnValue && (intValue == 2 || ((intValue == 3 || intValue == 4) && strValue));` is evaluated:

```js
/*
 * GIVEN:
 *   blnValue = blnX = false;
 *   intValue = intX = 3;
 *   strValue = strX = "2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z";
 */

/*0*/ !blnValue && (intValue == 2 || ((intValue == 3 || intValue == 4) && strValue));
/*1*/ !false && (3 == 2 || (( 3 == 3 || 3 == 4) && '2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z'));
/*2*/ true && (false || ((true || false) && '2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z'));
/*3*/ true && (false || (true && '2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z'));
/*4*/ true && (false || '2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z');
/*5*/ true && '2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z';
/*6*/ '2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z';
```

Also notice that:

```js
const a = true && '2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z';
const b = '2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z' && true;
console.log(a);  // -> '2021-03-25T13:53:13.259352Z'
console.log(b);  // -> true
```